# Strophe.js in-band Registration

Tags: javascript, xmpp, registration, strophe

I know that there are many other questions related to strophe in-band registration and XEP 0077 but my question is the following:

I'm trying to write in the correct form the following stanza:

```
<iq to='marlowe.shakespeare.lit' type='set'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <username>juliet</username>
    <password>R0m30</password>
    <name>JJ</name>
  </query>
</iq>
```

But I'm unable to write it correctly. I'm stuck on how to write the username, password, and name fields in javascript.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
connection.sendIQ($iq({to: "server", type: "set"}).c('query', {xmlns: "jabber:iq:register"}).c)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I think the [Strophe Plugin for In-Band Registration](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/register) is exactly what you were looking for!

```
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="strophe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="strophe.register.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
</head>
```

Javascript:

```
var callback = function (status) {
    if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTER) {
        connection.register.fields.username = "juliet";
        connection.register.fields.password = "R0m30";
        connection.register.submit();
    } else if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTERED) {
        console.log("registered!");
        connection.authenticate();
    } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        console.log("logged in!");
    } else {
        // every other status a connection.connect would receive
    }
};
connection.register.connect("example.com", callback, wait, hold);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Strophe and the connect function if you are going to use javascript.

connection.connect(jid, password, cb);

In-band registration is for non-javascript use. You would assemble the body and send the string to your jabber server. See http://metajack.im/2008/10/03/getting-attached-to-strophe/ for an example.

Comment: connection.connect can only be used after you register the user in the jabber server. My question was how to register the user using Strophe. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Far as I know, you can't register with Strophe/Javascript. The user has to be already registered on the jabber server. See last part of my answer. XEP 0077 can be handled by your back-end code, then the RID, SID and JID can passed out to Strophe to attach with. Or you can manually add users to your jabber server and then use the connect feature.